# Matlab matrix minimum value

Tags: matlab, matrix, minimum

I have a a matrix Number which contains

```
0.2728    0.2304    0.2008    0.1900    0.2008    0.2304    0.2728
0.2304    0.1786    0.1391    0.1233    0.1391    0.1786    0.2304
0.2008    0.1391    0.0843    0.0567    0.0843    0.1391    0.2008
0.1900    0.1233    0.0567    0.0100    0.0567    0.1233    0.1900
0.2008    0.1391    0.0843    0.0567    0.0843    0.1391    0.2008
0.2304    0.1786    0.1391    0.1233    0.1391    0.1786    0.2304
0.2728    0.2304    0.2008    0.1900    0.2008    0.2304    0.2728
```

I am trying to find the minimum value (or values if there are equal mins).
I have tried

[min_val,idx]=min(number);

[row,col]=ind2sub(size(number),idx);

I am getting row 4 which is right but col 1 which clearly not the min, min is in the center.
When I print min(number) I am give the whole of row 4 so I also tried

[min_val,idx]=min(min(number));

[row,col]=ind2sub(size(number),idx);

But i's giving the same result. I'm not really sure what's going on here. Any help would be appreciated!

Code used to get the positions of multiple minimums.

```
[min_val, idx] = min(number(:));%finds minimum value of n
mins = number==min_val;%logical array that gives 1 where number is at 
its minimum

ind1 = zeros();
ind2= zeros();
for i = 1:length(x)
    for j = 1:length(y)
        if min_val(i,j) == 1
            ind1 = [ind1;i];% indcies where mins = 1 
            ind2 = [ind2;j];
        
        end
    end
end
ind1 = ind1(ind1~=0);
```

Comment: I think the documentation is very clear about what is going on, and it should be straightforward to find your desired syntax: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html#d123e905216

Comment: Do you need all pairs of indices if there are several minimizing values, or just one? For example, what should the output for `[0.2 0.1; 0.1 0.3]` be?

Comment: I do need multiple, I seem to have it working using the below comment, it isn't giving me output exactly where i expect them, so I'm still looking into that! Sorry not used to using stack over flow, the comment below is not very legible!

Comment: Code used for multiple mins added to original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can use [**`min`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) and [**`ind2sub`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html) to achieve your expected output:

```
matlab:1> number = [0.2728 0.2304 0.2008 0.1900 0.2008 0.2304 0.2728; 0.2304 0.1786 0.1391 0.1233 0.1391 0.1786 0.2304; 0.2008 0.1391 0.0843 0.0567 0.0843 0.1391 0.2008; 0.1900 0.1233 0.0567 0.0100 0.0567 0.1233 0.1900; 0.2008 0.1391 0.0843 0.0567 0.0843 0.1391 0.2008; 0.2304 0.1786 0.1391 0.1233 0.1391 0.1786 0.2304; 0.2728 0.2304 0.2008 0.1900 0.2008 0.2304 0.2728]
number =

   0.272800   0.230400   0.200800   0.190000   0.200800   0.230400   0.272800
   0.230400   0.178600   0.139100   0.123300   0.139100   0.178600   0.230400
   0.200800   0.139100   0.084300   0.056700   0.084300   0.139100   0.200800
   0.190000   0.123300   0.056700   0.010000   0.056700   0.123300   0.190000
   0.200800   0.139100   0.084300   0.056700   0.084300   0.139100   0.200800
   0.230400   0.178600   0.139100   0.123300   0.139100   0.178600   0.230400
   0.272800   0.230400   0.200800   0.190000   0.200800   0.230400   0.272800

matlab:2> [min_val, idx] = min(number(:))
min_val = 0.010000
idx = 25
matlab:3> [row, col] = ind2sub(size(number), idx)
row = 4
col = 4
```